# How to do psexec using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

The following psexec runs good from my command prompt, it opens the GUI in the remote terminal:

```
psexec -s -i 1 \\135.20.230.160 -u administrator -p force  "C:
```

\Program Files (x86)\Tensilica\Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3\xt-ocd.exe"

How do I include the above psexec command in Python so that running the python script does the same thing? I am trying with subprocess call but yet to succeed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using python2.7 or python3? If the answer is "both" then please *remove* the version specific tags. Version specific tags should be used when you are targeting one version.

Comment: I am using Python 3 in my laptop, the remote machine is installed with 2.7